# create dictionary based on filter in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to get a data structure like this, based on a many-to-many relationship.

Say for example there is a table with `Users` and a table with `Roles`. A user can have many roles.

```
user_roles = db.Table(
    'user_roles',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Role.id), primary_key=True)
)
```

What I am trying to get is a data structure like this, where the `Role` is the key, and the list that follows is all the users of that role, like this

```
{
  'Write_Articles': ['<User Corvid>, <User Crow>'],
  'Delete_Articles': ['<User Corvid>'],
  'Change_Tags': ['<User Crow>', '<User Jeff>'],
  'Kitty_Cat': ['<User Kitty>']
}
```

How can this be achieved in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: If you've already have a many-to-many relationship set up, this should be fairly trivial, no? (`{r: r.users for r in Role.query}`) Or are you looking for how to set up the many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eager-load the relationship to avoid multiple queries, and use a dictionary comprehension to manipulate the results.

```
by_name = {g.name: g.users for g in Group.query.options(db.joinedload(Group.users))}
```